# Android Handlers - inter-thread communication

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

How do you implement two-way communication between two threads with Handlers in Android?

I have a Service A that spawns thread B. It's fairly easy to communicate from B to A, it's just to pass a Handler to the constructor of B, but how to do it from A to B? B does not have any Looper assigned to it automatically.

Has anyone got the answer?

Comment: Use can achieve it with HandlerThread. Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134683/android-toast-in-a-thread/45922317#45922317

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Here](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-passing-data-between-main.html) is good post explaining threads and communication using handlers. Also, the same blog has a number of posts regarding various thread constructs in Android

Comment: You shouldn't just give a link to another site as an answer, since the site may go out of date in the future. Instead, click the "edit" link on this answer, include the essential parts of the solution from that page here, and provide the link for reference. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259

Comment: Thanks Peter. In this case, I maintain the blog I have linked. So, if I update it, this answer is renewed too.

Answer (score 5):

To overcome the problem of getting a Handler for the Thread you just created (but which may not have initialized yet), see [How to create a Looper thread, then send it a message immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838207/how-to-create-a-looper-thread-then-send-it-a-message-immediately)

Answer (score 1):

Call `Looper.prepare()` in the new thread, and Looper will be created for you for that thread. Then you can create a Handler to pass back to the other thread.

That is, after calling `Looper.prepare()`, the statement `Handler h = new Handler()` will create a Handler on the Looper of your new thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html

Comment: A complete answer would suggest a method for passing the new thread's handler back to the other thread.

Comment: Specificly, to get a handler for the HandlerThread you just created, see "How to create a Looper thread, then send it a message immediately?": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838207/how-to-create-a-looper-thread-then-send-it-a-message-immediately

Answer (score -1):

You Can Follow the Below Steps to implement two-way communication.

1) Create a worker thread which extends Thread Class .
2) Initialize a Handler with this worker Thread .
3) In its run() method prepare the looper for this thread by : Looper.prepare() for binding message queue to this thread and Looper.loop() to create a loop   which will read the message and runnables from the Message Queue of this thread.

4) Send Messgae and Runnables from the UI Thread handler to this worker thread handler using the post() for runnables & sendMessage() for Messages .

Please refer this tutorial : [Handle background work using Looper](http://androidheap.com/Loopers-In-Android.php)