# Call a calling thread function from the called thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler

I have an Android library class. This class is used to manage a bluetooth connection, when the socket connection is created, is starts a new thread that waits on bluetooth socket for incoming message received from a bluetooth device.

When I receive a new message I would call a function running on calling thread, I tried to use [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to do it, but the `handleMessage()` function ran always on secondary thread.

```
public class LibraryClass {

    private ConnectedThread ct;

    LibraryClass() {
        // start blutooth connection
        ct = new ConnectedThread();
        ct.start();
    }

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            // this code is running on ConnectionThread but I need to handle
            // message on primary thread
            }
        }
    };

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                mHandler.dispatchMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could you help me to solve this issue?

Comment: A `Handler` is linked to **that** thread which executes `new Handler();`. And thread must have a `Looper` running in order to use a `Handler`.

Comment: Threads don't have functions. Objects have methods. If you need to call a method on an object from outside that object, make sure that the calling context has a reference to the object instance available.

Comment: User117 the Handler is correctly created on main thread and all works correctly, but I call dispatchMessage from secondary thread and my expection is that the handleMessage event handler should run on main thread, but unfortunately it run on secondary thread (the same one where I called the dispatchMessage method).

Comment: EJP, I'm sorry but I user wrong term, I need to call a method (and I'm able to do it). My needs is that I should call the method from secondary thread and it should run on primary thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Handlers - inter-thread communication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657968/android-handlers-inter-thread-communication)