# Communication between two threads, thread communication over resultreceiver

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have two Questions, and i hope that you can give me a solution without my code cause it is not existing, yet !

First Question : 
How can i communicate between 2 Threads, what would be the easiest way to send for example an integer or a string from thread1 to thread2 ?

Second Question : 
Is there a way, to communicate between a Activity and a Thread over an Result Receiver, when the Thread ist starded by a Service, wich is startet by the Activity ?

Thanks in advice !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657968/android-handlers-inter-thread-communication

Comment: Questions about code that does not exist are not really within the scope of StackOverflow, but...

Comment: ...Probably the most versatile way to communicate between two threads is to have them share a blocking queue (or two queues if you want two-way communication).  There are other, more specialized ways.  Have a look in the `java.util.concurrent` package for some of them.  Sorry, I don't know any Android specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question isn't all that useful for us to help you,(we would need code, etc. first) But I happen to be able to give 'broad' answers...

**First question:** "easiest" way... is completely subjective...

First of all you have LOTS AND LOTS of options on Android (more than even just normal Java)...

You could use standard java concurrency stuff...

you can use Android's HaMeR (Handlers, Messages, and Runnables) (so named from my PhD adviser, [Dr Schmidt](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZ9NgFYEMxp4KSJPUyaQCj7x--NQ6kvcX) who has several CS Courses online that you can watch for free.. (playlist titled: `CS 282 (2014): Concurrent Java Network Programming in Android` and `CS 282 (2013): Systems Programming for Android`)

The fact that concurrency on android can make an entire university course(s) is a *strong* indicator as to how complex the topic is...

Depending on 'exactly' how you want the threads to communicate... I would personally recommend making a custom handler in the UI thread and giving that reference to the threads (if they report results to the UI thread) Or making a handler in each thread and letting the other thread reference it. (thereby giving the threads a  mechanism to asyncly communicate back and forth.)

[detailed video explaining Handlers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDvjU8HSuYE&index=33&list=PLZ9NgFYEMxp4KSJPUyaQCj7x--NQ6kvcX)

"easy" is subjective here...

**Second Question:**

You wouldn't communicate with the 'thread' behind the service... You would start the service and communicate with the service. The service would then communicate with the thread(s) that it is controlling.

I would personally recommend one-way asynchronous AIDL with custom callbacks for setting up a service (But that is a rather advanced method(Which I won't use any other means for bound service anymore because every other means is all vastly inferior in my opinion))

However until you get to that point, I would suggest just following the 1st question's approach of making handlers that allow you to pass messages  back and forth, and then have the service 'report' the results to the Activity when it gets them (from one or more threads)