# How to force main thread to wait until Looper will end its work

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am using `Looper` inside a `Service` on Android app. Usually it is working without any issue. But in some cases (for example very often when I am trying to debug my app) it shows up that there is a race inside the app. `Looper` is starting, `Thread` and `Handler` are creating in the method `startMessageThread()` which is being invoked at the end of the `Service.onCreate()` method.

The race is because there are other methods and classes which use this class initialized before `Looper.loop();`. And in some cases these methods are running before `Looper` ends. It results in `NullPointerException`.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private Thread thread;
    private Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //some code
        startMessageThread();
    }

    private void startMessageThread() {
        thread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() { 
                Looper.prepare();
                handler = new Handler() {

                    @Override
                    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                        switch (msg.what) {
                            //message handling
                        }
                    }
                };
                MyObject myObject = new MyObject(arg1, arg2);
                myObject.init();
                myObject.attr = myAttr;
                Looper.loop();
            }
        }              
    }
}
```

If I am right, it is quite similar for this question [How to create a Looper thread, then send it a message immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838207/how-to-create-a-looper-thread-then-send-it-a-message-immediately) But I don't want to send any message immediately after creating 'HandlerThread'. Just to force main thread to wait in the end of the `onCreate` method for the `Looper` ends.

I have tried with this added at the end of the `Service.onCreate` method:

```
synchronized (thread) {
    try {
        if (looperRun) {
            wait();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`looperRun` is of course `boolean`. I have added `looperRun = true;` before `Looper.loor();` method invocation. And this code at the end of the `startMessageThread()` method.

```
if (looperRun) {            
    notify();
    looperRun = false;
}
```

In some cases I have got this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.myapplication.service.MyService:
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2582)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
    at com.myapplication.service.MyService.onCreate(MyService.java:162)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2572)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT**

```
protected void startMessageThread() {
    MessageThread messageThread = new MessageThread("messageThread");
    messageThread.start();
    messageHandler = new Handler(messageThread.getLooper()) {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                //message handling
            }
        }
    };
}

private class MessageThread extends HandlerThread {

    public MessageThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject(arg1, arg2);
        myObject.init();
        myObject.attr = myAttr;
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I have tried with solution similar to this: [How to create a Looper thread, then send it a message immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838207/how-to-create-a-looper-thread-then-send-it-a-message-immediately) My code is below. However my app seems to be frozen after start.

```
private class BackgroundThread extends HandlerThread {

    private Handler handler;

    public BackgroundThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        backgroundHandler = new Handler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                log.finest("DEAService message:" + msg.what);
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case MSG_INIT:                            
                        MyObject myObject = new MyObject(arg1, arg2);
                        myObject.init();
                        myObject.attr = myAttr;
                        break;
                    //message handling
                }
            }
        };
        Looper.loop();
    };

    public synchronized void waitUntilReady() {
        handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
    }
}
```

I start this `HandlerThread` in this method as previously:

```
protected void startBackgroundThread() {
    BackgroundThread backgroundThread = new BackgroundThread("backgroundThread");
    backgroundThread.start();
    backgroundThread.waitUntilReady();
    backgroundHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_INIT);
}
```

As I mentioned above - app seems to be frozen after start. Nothing happens.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @OfekRon I would like to wait for a while inside `onCreate` as `Looper` will be finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with this code and everything seems to be working fine.

```
private class BackgroundThread extends HandlerThread {

    private Handler handler;

    public BackgroundThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        backgroundHandler = new Handler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                log.finest("DEAService message:" + msg.what);
                switch (msg.what) {
                    //message handling
                }
            }
        };
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject(arg1, arg2);
        myObject.init();
        myObject.attr = myAttr;
        Looper.loop();
    };

    public synchronized void waitUntilReady() {
        handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
    }
}
```

And start this `HandlerThread` with this code:

```
protected void startBackgroundThread() {
    BackgroundThread backgroundThread = new BackgroundThread("backgroundThread");
    backgroundThread.start();
    backgroundThread.waitUntilReady();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should never, ever block the main thread. Never!

I've used several times without any issue the nice handy `HandlerThread` class like this:

```
HandlerThread ht = new HandlerThread("myThread");
ht.start();
Handler handler = new Handler(ht.getLooper());
handler.post(... stuff
```

maybe you should give it a try

**edit:**
sorry, there're two ways of doing handlers, my original post is the other one. The way you're using is like that.

```
HandlerThread ht = new HandlerThread("myThread");
ht.start();
Handler handler = new Handler(ht.getLooper()){
      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            //message handling
        }
   }
};
```

**new edit:**

see the code.

```
protected void startMessageThread() {
    HandlerThread messageThread = new HandlerThread("messageThread");
    messageThread.start();
    messageHandler = new Handler(messageThread.getLooper()) {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          switch (msg.what) {
              case INIT:
                 MyObject myObject = new MyObject(arg1, arg2);
                 myObject.init();
                 myObject.attr = myAttr; 
              break;
            }
        }
    };
   messageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(INIT);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I can switch my `Thread` to a `HandlerThread`. But what stuff I could post by `handler` created in this way? I can't place in this way any code which is running after `onCreate` completion.

Comment: I have once more question: where should I place in this way my code I mentioned in question, which is placed in the `run()` method before `Looper.loop()`? If I am right I could extend `HandlerThread` and place it in the `run()` method. But should I place also in this `run()` method `Looper.prepare()` and `Looper.loop()`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. From what I posted on the answer you have to keep a reference for the `handler` Object and call `handler.sendMessage(...)` that will be handled inside the the `switch` statement. No need to extend `HandlerThread` you're already extending the `Handler`

Comment: OK, I am not clear and perfect in English. :-) I have updated my question. I have added in my question first version three lines of code before `Looper.loop()` and I have also added the solution I am wondering about. This is what I have described in previous comment. These three code lines are very important so I should place them in this `Thread`.

Comment: check my second edition. I don't know what your object is doing, but seems like you could do like that. I never mixed a Looper thread with some other type of code. Not sure how this will do

Comment: I've re-edited the answer, something like that seems like possible.

Comment: I am going to test it out today. It looks quite promising. :-)